# What is the meaning of tuple under function definition

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, vgg-net

recently, I read codes from https://github.com/danfeiX/scene-graph-TF-release/

In `lib/fast-rcnn/models.py`, there are lots of tuple-under-function style code.
for example, _vgg_fc()

```
def _vgg_fc(self):
    (self.feed('conv_out', 'rois')
    .roi_pool(7, 7, 1.0/16, name='pool5')
    .fc(4096, name='fc6')
    .dropout(self.keep_prob, name='drop6')
    .fc(4096, name='fc7')
    .dropout(self.keep_prob, name='vgg_out'))
```

I wonder what is the different from the code below?

```
def _vgg_fc(self):
    self.feed('conv_out', 'rois')
    .roi_pool(7, 7, 1.0/16, name='pool5')
    .fc(4096, name='fc6')
    .dropout(self.keep_prob, name='drop6')
    .fc(4096, name='fc7')
    .dropout(self.keep_prob, name='vgg_out')
```

Comment: That's not a tuple. Putting parentheses around a thing doesn't automatically make it a tuple.

Comment: Indeed, tuples often don't even require parentheses.